# undefined method `agendas' for nil:NilClass Actioncontroller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Essentially I have an app usong Devise, i've a user model and an agenda model. Agenda 'belongs_to' user and user 'has_many" agenda, these are my db relationships. I can fire up IRB and get db data correctly
    user = User.first
    user.agendas
and I will get a list of all posts that belong to that user
My problem occurs upon signing in, the user is redirected to home#index but I get a NoMethodError in Home#index undefined method `agendas' for nil:NilClass
I'm sure i'm missing something. Do I need an index method in my agenda controller also?
..app/views/home/index.html.erb

```
<h3>Home</h3>
<div class="row">
    <div class="span8">
        <% if @user.agendas.any? %>
        <h3>Agendas</h3>
        <ol class="agendas">
            <%= render @agendas %>
        </ol>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

my home_controller.rb

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @agendas = current_user.agendas.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end
```

My agenda controller just has a create and destroy stub for future code. 
its model /agenda.rb

```
class Agenda < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title
  belongs_to :user

  validates :title, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 }
  validates :user_id, presence: true

  default_scope order: 'agendas.created_at DESC'
end
```

Comment: caught my myproblem ...home.html.erb should be current_user.agendas.any?

Comment: but the agendas are not populating, anyone see any issues with display code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is coming from this:

```
<% if @user.agendas.any? %>
```

and the error says that `@user` is `nil`. Your controller says:

```
def index
  @agendas = ...
end
```

I don't see `@user` being assigned a value in there. I don't think your `authenticate_user!` filter is setting `@user` either. So you could do this:

```
def index
  @user    = current_user
  @agendas = @user.agendas.paginate(page: params[:page])
end
```

And then:

```
<% if @user.agendas.any? %>
  <h3>Agendas</h3>
  <ol class="agendas">
    <%= render @agendas %>
  </ol>
<% end %>
```

You could also access `current_user` directly in your ERB:

```
<% if current_user.agendas.any? %>
  <h3>Agendas</h3>
  <ol class="agendas">
    <%= render @agendas %>
  </ol>
<% end %>
```

But keep in mind that you've already gone to the trouble of computing `@agendas` so why not just look at that and leave your controller alone?

```
<% if @agendas.present? %>
  <h3>Agendas</h3>
  <ol class="agendas">
    <%= render @agendas %>
  </ol>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I found it.